# Converting objective-c block to Swift closure

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am trying to convert this Objective-C block into Swift:

```
[self.client downloadEntity:@"Students" withParams: nil success:^(id response) {
      // execute code
}
failure:^(NSError *error) {
    // Execute code

}];
```

This is my code in Swift, but the syntax seems to be a bit off:

```
    client.downloadEntity("Students", withParams: nil, success:  {(students: [AnyObject]!) -> Void in
        print("here")
        },  failure:  { (error: NSError!) -> Void! in
            print ("here")
     }
```

This is giving me a few compilation errors:

1. Value of 'AnyObject' has no member 'downloadEntity'
2. It is complaining about the lack of commas (,) right after the failure part of the code

Comment: What makes you think there's a problem with the code? Does it give you compilation errors? Does it give runtime errors?

Comment: Yes. Compilation errors. I added them above

Comment: client has no member 'downloadEntity', maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Error from #1 has nothing to do with the comma, clang complains about an object not having the `downloadEntity` member. What data type does the `client` variable has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
client.downloadEntity("Student", withParams: nil,
        success: { (responseObj) -> Void in
            print("success: \(responseObj)")
        },

        failure: { (errorObj) -> Void in
            print("treat here (in this block) the error! error:\(errorObj)")
        })
```

Comment: This answer is a great start, is there any way to add an explanation of how your solution solves the problem?

Comment: There were only syntax errors. Xcode autocompletion feature will help you to use the correct Swift equivalent method.  So AnyObject? should be changed with the object name. That's all

Answer (score 2):

You need to switch to the new Swift error syntax, and you can also using trailing closures. I had to use a bool for the example to show how you would call your success closure, or you would throw an error.

```
var wasSuccessful = true // This is just here so this compiles and runs

// This is a custom error type. If you are using something that throws an
// NSError, you don't need this.
enum Error:ErrorType {
    case DownloadFailed
}

// Hopefully you have control over this method and you can update
// the signature and body to something similar to this:
func downloadEntity(entityName: String, success: ([AnyObject]) -> Void)  throws {
    let students = [AnyObject]()

    // download your entity
    if wasSuccessful {
        // Call your success completion handler
        success(students)
    }
    else {
        throw Error.DownloadFailed
    }
}
```

When you have a function that can throw an error, you need to call it with try inside a do/catch block.

```
// Calling a function that can throw
do {
    try downloadEntity("Students") { students in 
        print("Download Succeded")
    }
}
catch Error.DownloadFailed {
    print("Download Failed")
}
// If you are handling NSError use this block instead of the one above
// catch let error as NSError {
//     print(error.description)
// }
```